# How to find element exist in the array?

Tags: perl

If $client_id doesn't exist in @ping_host it has to pass the if condition, but it only pass when the @ping_host is empty. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
if ( !grep( $client_id, @ping_host ) ) {
            print "Client Id $client_name doesn't exist \n";
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's somewhat inefficient to use `grep` for this, because it returns *all* matches in the array, whereas you only care if it has at least one. You could use `none` for this like:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(none);
if(none { $client_id eq $_ } @ping_host) {
    print "Client Id $client_name doesn't exist \n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First `grep` parameter should be a test which returns boolean value for each element of `@ping_host` array,

```
if ( !grep( $client_id eq $_, @ping_host ) ) {
  print "Client Id $client_name doesn't exist \n";
}
```

Comment: is this the same too if (! grep {$_ eq $client_id} @ping_host)

Comment: @user1595858 yes, these are equivalents.